# Kendo UI plugin use to export PDF not working in Iphone Safari

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, kendo-ui, export

I am using the Kendo UI plugin to export PDF from html which is working fine in Desktop (Chrome, mozilla, edge), Android (chrome, mozilla) Devices and Mac Book (chrome, safari) but on the iPhone and iPad the export function is not working in safari browser though its working for chrome browser. If anyone has any solution, please help.

I try a different approach like proxy url still not working. My expectation is to export pdf from html in iPhone and iPad safari browser using Kendo a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like Export PDF is supported on mobile for various technical reasons.

From [this thread](https://www.telerik.com/forums/export-pdf-on-ipad):

> The PDF Export on mobile devices is not officially supported. Even though exporting in PDF might work on some mobile devices in specific scenarios, on others, the odds of failing are quite possible. PDF export is not supported in mobile browsers and hybrid mobile applications as described in the following article:
>
> https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/limitations-browser-support#browser-support

and if you follow that link in the quoted response - this is the relevant bit:

> **Browser Support**
>
> - Internet Explorer 9 and later
> - Latest Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Blink-based Opera versions
>
> Because of browser limitations and CORS-related security restrictions, **PDF export is not supported for mobile**—for example, locally stored font files cannot be loaded in hybrid applications. While in specific scenarios PDF export might still work on mobile devices, it is not supported by mobile browsers and hybrid applications.

Comment: Thanks for the technical clarification. Is there any alternative plugin available which allow us to export PDF in iphone safari similar to kendo UI?